# Is it possible to make smart contract that charges user 0.1 eth once a month?

Tags: web3js, blockchain

is it possible to make smart contract that charges user 0.1 eth once a month?( after user confirms that he agrees)

Answer (score 1):

There isn't such option in smart contracts. You wouldn't want such either.
Think about what will happen if the account ran out of ethers so he can't transfer 0.1 eth after a month?